# Python 2.7 - finding UTF-8 characters

Tags: python-2.7, utf-8

```
from urllib import urlopen
web = urlopen("http://typographyforlawyers.com/straight-and-curly-
quotes.html").read()
web = web.replace("\xe2\x80\x9c".decode('utf8'), '"')
```

"\xe2\x80\x9c" is the UTF-8 character for curly quotes. When I try to find curly quotes in a website using this code, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
web = web.replace("\xe2\x80\x9c".decode('utf8'), '"')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 2265: 
ordinal not in range(128)
```

What does this error mean, what am I doing wrong, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use decode('utf-8') to decode the string.

```
from urllib import urlopen

web = urlopen("http://typographyforlawyers.com/straight-and-curly-quotes.html").read().decode('utf-8')
web = web.replace(b"\xe2\x80\x9c".decode('utf8'), '"')

print(web)
```

Comment: I like this answer but the explanation could be more explicit. It converts the web response to unicode and uses a `bytes` object for decode so that there is no reason to touch the ascii codec. It should also be mentioned that HTML documents frequently put their encoding in a `<meta>` tag and `utf-8` may not be the right guess. Its usually right, but not guaranteed.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer, it makes sense as well.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the Python 2 interpreter using the "ascii" codec as default for the string literals. In future code (Python 3) the default is utf-8 and you can have unicode literal characters in your code. You can do that now, with your Python 2, using a future import.

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from urllib import urlopen

web = urlopen("http://typographyforlawyers.com/straight-and-curly-quotes.html").read()
web = web.decode("utf-8")
web = web.replace('“' , '"')

print(repr(web))
```

Comment: `unicode_literal` has many potential pitfalls. `web.decode("utf-8")` fixed the problem. The rest is risky.

Comment: I'm not clear what the OP actually wants. But `unicode_literal` may have pitfalls, but not if you use it correctly. For a small script such as this it would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Note that this is a python 2 solution. Python 3 handles strings and bytes differently.

I can reproduce the problem with

```
>>> web = "0123\xe2\x80\x9c789"
>>> web.replace("\xe2\x80\x9c".decode('utf-8'), '"')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)
```

You read an encoded string into `web` and I just made a simpler one for test. When you decoded the search string, you created a unicode object. For the replacement to work, `web` needs to be converted to unicode.

```
>>> "\xe2\x80\x9c".decode('utf-8')
u'\u201c'
>>> unicode(web)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)
```

It was the `web` conversion that got you. In python 2, `str` can hold encoded bytes - and that's exactly what you have here. One option is to just replace the encoded byte sequence

```
>>> web.replace("\xe2\x80\x9c", '"')
'0123"789'
```

This only works because you knew the page was encoded with utf-8. That is usually the case, but worth the mention.